# Lexicographic and Reverse Lexicographic Ordering

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Perhaps dumb question, I just want to make sure there isn't some edge case I'm missing - when we're looking at say the lexicographic and reverse lexicographic monomial ordering of some monomials, are they just "reverses of each other?"

Let us say we have $a>b>c>d$. In the lex ordering, if we have say $a^2>ab>b^2>bc$, then does it follow that in the revlex ordering, we have $bc>b^2>ab>a^2?$

Comment: What do you mean by “reverse lexicographic ordering”? Is it literally the opposite ordering? Or are you reversing the direction you read the word?

Comment: The fundamental notion of [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) applies to finite strings (sequences) of symbols drawn from an ordered alphabet.  You wish to apply the ideas to [monomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Monomials), so already there is a need for you to clarify your meaning. In a lexicographic order (with the usual alphabet) string $bc$ comes before $cb$, but in your application these strings correspond to equal monomials.

Comment: @hardmath I made some clarification in the original post

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I wonder if your motive is to understand the terms *lexicographic* and *reverse lexicographic* ordering as some (unnamed) author used them, or to decide what term best would describe an ordering you intend to use.  The example you give happens to involve monomials which all have (total) degree two, but you did not specify that a restriction of this kind forms the domain of monomials to be ordered.  Further clarification would be valuable.